# Rails finding the Domain Name from a domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
domain = email.split("@").last
```

Which takes an EMAIL like (steve.jobs@apple.com) and returns apple.com

I would like to know how to get just apple just the domain name, without the extension. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Domain names don't have "extensions" they are just domain names and subdomains. What if you came across this address:

```
an.apprentice@mail.somecompany.co.uk
```

what pieces did you want?

You can take your split a step further

```
domainPieces = domain.split(".")
```

but then you have to decide what you want to do with those pieces.

possible code:

```
# expand this list
closedTlds = [ 'uk', 'pro' ]
# expand this list too
fullDomains = [ 'del.icio.us' ]

whoKnowsWhatThisActuallyMeans = ''

domain = email.split("@").last
domainPieces = domain.split(".")

if fullDomains.include?(domain)
    whoKnowsWhatThisActuallyMeans = domain
else
    if closedTlds.include?(domainPieces.Last)
        whoKnowsWhatThisActuallyMeans = domainPieces[-3]
    else
        whoKnowsWhatThisActuallyMeans = domainPieces[-2]
    end
end

whoKnowsWhatThisActuallyMeans # should return the correct value
```

I'm still learning ruby, so I think the syntax is right, but I'm not sure.

Comment: exactly which is why I'm looking for expert opinions :)

Comment: You haven't described what problem you're trying to solve. All you've said is that you want to remove the "extension" but you haven't described what you mean. There are a bunch of "TLDs" (top-level domains), these include standard things like ".com", ".org", ".net", less common ones like ".museum", ".info", ".pro" and a bunch of two-letter country code domains, like ".uk", ".cn", ".jp". Each TLD has a group that is in charge of how the subdomains work underneath it. ".com" has an open policy, where basically any domain name can be registered,

Comment: where domains like ".pro" and ".uk" only allow certain subdomains, which are then opened. In any case. the owner of any domain, can decide whether or not to allow sub domains. At one point, I was in charge of the domain msdnaa.cs.byu.edu, and I was in charge of deciding whether or not to allow subdomains underneath it. There's virtually no limit on how many subdomains are allowed. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Good question. I want a friendly domain name to display... So if you register from an apple.com name I can say your company Name is Apple

Comment: So, what would you want it to display if the domain was del.icio.us? mail.apple.com? what about google.co.uk? mail.msdnaa.cs.byu.edu? You haven't described how you want to determine what the friendly name is? del.icio.us is known for it's domain name hacking. The name of the company is del.icio.us, you can't trim anything. You can't possibly know all of the domains that this works with. If you must have an algorithm, I'd probably maintain a list of which domains require a subdomain (.uk, .pro), and otherwise, just use the second-level domain, unless it's in a different list (like del.icio.us)

Comment: Another possiblity is to take the domain, send it to internic's whois, and grab the company name from the registry, but doesn't work for all domains, doesn't always return the correct company name, and you aren't allowed to hit the registry in an automated fashion.

Comment: That's just for removing higher level domains. Did you want to also remove subdomains? Did you want to treat cs.byu.edu different from byu.edu? What if they have an email address domain of gmail.com, are you going to say that their company name is gmail? Also, how are you going to handle capitalization? You can't just capitalize the first letter of the domain. "Byu" looks kinda funny.

Comment: @AnApprentice Well, I added some code that might do what you might be looking for.